# How can I solve the problem of receiving multi-byte characters in the shell "read" command?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, archlinux, manjaro

Use read to receive user input, as follows:

```sh
$ read -r demo
演示
```

But the user found an input error. He pressed the backspace key for the first time and wanted to delete a character. The result was this:

[image]

The character "示" is only half deleted.You need to press twice to completely delete the character "示".

[image]

But no matter how many times I press backspace, the character "演" will not be deleted.

But the demo variable has no value.

```sh
$ echo $demo
```

This is some of my environmental information:

```
shell: zsh 5.8 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
shell theme: oh-my-zsh bira
system: manjaro linux 21.1.2
Desktop environment: kde 5.85.0
KDE Plasma: 5.22.5
Qt: 5.15.2
Kernel: 5.10.61-1-MANJARO (64-bit)
GUI: X11
Analog terminal: Konsole
Font: JetBrains Mono
LC_ALL: zh_CN.UTF-8
LANG: zh_CN.UTF-8
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suppose the reason is that the editing during `read` is done through the terminal capabilities alone and not through `readline` like when editing a command. You may be interested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113450/90785). In advanced shells you *can* enable editing, as detailed in that answer, with special commands (for zsh: vared).

Comment: maybe try `read -e`?

Comment: Not an answer, but some background that I think explains what you are seeing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms

Comment: @aszswasz : Could be a problem by your terminal. You did not say which one you are using, but in any case, this question is better asked at [su].